# Правильно ли построено предложение? Какие знаки препинания требуются?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

**Италия не очень жалует беспроводной интернет поэтому он не везде.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна запятая, перед после слова "интернет", т. к. это сложное предложение.